# creating a new variable based on string matching

Tags: r, if-statement

I have the following dataframe:

```
df <- data.frame(Sample_name = c("01_00H_NA_DNA",   "01_00H_NA_RNA",    "01_00H_NA_S",  "01_00H_NW_DNA",    "01_00H_NW_RNA",    "01_00H_NW_S",  "01_00H_OM_DNA",    "01_00H_OM_RNA",    "01_00H_OM_S",  "01_00H_RL_DNA",    "01_00H_RL_RNA",    "01_00H_RL_S"),
             Pair = c("","", "S1","","","S2","","","S3","", "","S5"))
```

I am trying to create a new variable `treatment` based on `sample_name`. I used the following code:
     `df$treatment <- ifelse(grep("_NA_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T), "nat", 
                            ifelse(grep("_NW_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T), "natH2",
                                   ifelse(grep("_RL_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T), "RNALat",
                                          ifelse(grep("_OM_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T ), "Om"))))`

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here, I got an error saying 
`Error in $<-.data.frame(*tmp*, "treatment", value = logical(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 12`

Any suggestions?

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: Probably `grepl` instead of `grep`.

Comment: expected output is if sample_name has "NA", treatment variable = "nat", if sample_name has "NW", treatment variable = "natH2", if sample_name has "OM", treatment variable = "Om", if sample_name has "RL", treatment variable = "RNALat". Another note if I use `grepl` in the beginning i.e `ifelse(grepl("_NA_"` then I don't get the error but `RL` and `OM` don't get substituted

Comment: Update, added `grepl` for all ifelse statements and it works. Did not quite get the difference between grep and grepl. Thanks, though!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Got the answer, added grepl to each grep statement:

```
df$treatment <- ifelse(grepl("_NA_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T), "nat", 
                        ifelse(grepl("_NW_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T ), "natH2",
                               ifelse(grepl("_RL_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T), "RNALat",
                                      ifelse(grepl("_OM_", df$sample_name, ignore.case = T ), "Om", "NA"))))
```